# ADT Plugin Error

Tags: eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin, adt

I desided to update my SDK in Eclipse. I go to SDK Manager and update Android SDK Tool to the latest version. Then I open Eclipse and it shows me a warning message:

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above. Current version is 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685. Please update ADT to the latest version.

I deside to update my ADT plugin (Help > Install New Software > ADT Plugin - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and I get above error:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240) Software currently installed: Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685) Only one of the following can be installed at once: Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger 23.0.3.1327240) Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240) To: com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger [23.0.3.1327240] Cannot satisfy dependency:

Could you help me please? I´m very depressed because I couldn´t do now nothing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

goto window - ANDROID SDK MANAGER check for updates and install and update the tools package after updating install and update your adt plugin

hopes it fix the error

Answer (score 0):

To resolve dependency issue in Eclipse, try to remove older version.

In `Help| About Eclipse| Installation Details`, you can find Software currently installed.
[image]
Uninstall all those and then you can install fresh `Android Development Tools for Eclipse` from `Eclipse Marketplace...| Popular`.
Hope this resolves.